# "It had a lot of interest for me"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was watching "12 angry men", and there's a line

> "What did you think of the case? I mean, it had a lot of interest for me."

By referring to the context, it sure means that the case "interested" the guy.
But I wonder whether "it had a lot of interest for me" is a correct usage, for example,

> "Julie has a lot of interest for Peter"

In this sentence, would it be a bit confusing about who likes who? It should be

Julie has a lot interest in Peter?
Or
Julie interests Peter a lot?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Just because something is ambiguous in context B, doesn't make it incorrect in context A. *Most* words in most languages are ambiguous.

Comment: Just to add. since 'interest' is a noun, in the second example the meaning would be that Julie has a lot of interest to give to Peter.

Answer (score 1):

*Interest* gets around.

**It interested me.

It was of interest to me.

It was interesting for me.

I was interested in it.

I was interested by it.

I found it interesting.

It held my interest.**

I would be interested to know if this is of any interest.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 'had a lot of interest for me'

I propose 'held a lot of interest for me'... since
'had' kind of seems less specific in the context.

Comment: Please explain your answer. Also, please format your answer so it makes sense when read.